# Pre-Populate wp-login.php Username

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP site whereby i send customers an email with a link to /my-quotes/ this then, has the following code:

```
<?
if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<? echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
<? endif; ?>
```

What i want to do is, give the link in the email like:
/my-quotes/?login=myusername

and that 'myusername' is the login fields value to save the user re-typing it.

I've had a look in wp-login.php and cant work out where to populate the login fields using $_GET, can anyone advise on a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it by hooking in to the `login_form` action, rather than modifying wp-login.php, which will get overwritten at next update.

You can add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// As part of WP login form construction, call our function
add_filter ( 'login_form', 'login_form_prepop' );

function login_form_prepop(){
    // Output jQuery to pre-fill the box

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['myusername'] ) ) { // Make sure a username was passed
?>
<!-- Small jQuery script to set the value of the input field to your variable -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#user_login").val( '<?php echo( $_REQUEST['myusername'] ); ?>' );
});
</script>
<?php
    }
}
```

Then update your code to include the variable:

```
<?
if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<? echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>?myusername=username">
<? endif; ?>
```

If the jQuery footprint is too much, you can achieve the same with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById("user_login");
el.value = "<?php echo( $_REQUEST['myusername'] ); ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks So Much! i had to edit the URL and change the code to &myusername= as it also included the redirecturl in the URl string.

Comment: Another question i have is:
`code` <?php
/*
Template Name: My Quotes List
*/
?>
<?
if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<? echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>&myusername=username">
<? endif; ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
`code`

The page seems to load then this re-direct is executed, is there a way to redirect before the page is rendered to the user?

Comment: Another question i have is: code <?php /* Template Name: My Quotes List */ ?> <? if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<? echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>&myusername=username"> <? endif; ?> <?php get_header(); ?> code The page seems to load then this re-direct is executed, is there a way to redirect before the page is rendered to the user?

Comment: Yes, by using the META refresh, the server is sending instruction back to the client, the client renders that page in the browser, then the browser redirects. That's what is causing the pause. Instead, use PHP's `header()` to send redirect information.

`<?php /* Template Name: My Quotes List */ ?> <? if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?><?php header('Location: ' . wp_login_url(get_permalink()) . '&myusername=username' ); die(); ?><? endif; ?> <?php get_header(); ?>`